# Different InfoWindow for different markers

Tags: android, infowindow, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using the Google Maps v2 API and places markers on the map. The markers represent different things and so I want to have a custom InfoWindow layout for each class of marker. The problem is that overriding `getInfoContents` and `getInfoWindow`, which are called each time a marker is selected, will supply the same layout for each marker.

Is there a different way to do this so that I can inflate a different layout for different groups of markers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem is that overriding getInfoContents and getInfoWindow, which are called each time a marker is selected, will supply the same layout for each marker.

They certainly do not have to do so. You are passed the `Marker` as a parameter to each method, and therefore can do something different based upon information in the `Marker`.

Comment: Agreed - you can use the information in each marker differently. For example the title and snippet could be different between marker A and marker B. However, isn't the XML layout inflated by getInfoContents/getInfoWindow the same in both cases?

Comment: @Rarw: Not necessarily. You are the one doing the inflating. You can use data control structures like `if` and `else` to choose different layouts to inflate.

Comment: got it - I'll add a key to one of the marker values and check that way.

Comment: @Rarw: Adding a key is problematic, insofar as `Marker` is final. The technique I am currently recommending is to overload the snippet to serve as this key. If you have more model data, you can use a `HashMap` keyed by that snippet, to look up the additional information. There are probably other approaches as well.

Comment: Even if it is an old post I haven't found any other solution and anyone else providing a nice way to accomplish this specific result. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

But you can. make your check before you inflating the the marker's `InfoWindow` and inflate a different layout based on your check.

when you receive the `Marker` in the  `public View getInfoContents(Marker args)` method create an if statement that will test if this marker corresponding to the type you want and inflate the relevant layout based on this.

you could check for example what is the position coordinates of the marker by running

`clickMarkerLatLng = args.getPosition();`

and based on this determin what `InfoWindow` should be presented.

Answer (score 1):

its very simple
map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

```
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                View v;
                LayoutInflater inflator=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v=inflator.inflate(R.layout.info_inflator, null);
                TextView text=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.title);
                Button ok_button=(Button) v.findViewById(R.id.ok_button);
                text.setText(marker.getTitle());
                ok_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });

                return v;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
        });
```

Comment: you can compare inside getifowindow...there you have marker to compare

Comment: What I ended up doing was adding a key/tag to the beginning of the snippet, extracting that tag from the marker passed to getinfowindow and then using a switch statement to control what window was displayed